# How can I get Slik SVN to accept an ssl certificate despite an 'unknown error'?

Tags: svn, ssl

I am trying to use Slik SVN to automate some functions regarding one of our subversion repositories. This requires SSL access.

I am unable to do this in an automated way because the request keeps on getting a "The certificate has an unknown error" response. I cannot work out why or how to fix it.

I want to know if there is a way to force Slik SVN to accept the certificate despite the errors.

The certificate is fine. I can confirm that it is the certificate installed on the server, as it's one of ours.

When running from a command line context, this is the result that I'm getting. Key values have been altered

```
C:\Users\Daniel>svn checkout "https://my-sub-domain.mydomain.net.nz/repository/path/to/key/folder/" "C:\path\to\local\folder" --force --depth infinity --username MyUsername --password MyPassword --no-auth-cache --ignore-externals
Error validating server certificate for 'https://my-sub-domain.mydomain.net.nz:443':
 - The certificate has an unknown error.
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: *.mydomain.net.nz
 - Valid: from Oct  9 00:00:00 2012 GMT until Nov  5 23:59:59 2017 GMT
 - Issuer: COMODO CA Limited, Salford, Greater Manchester, GB
 - Fingerprint: 00:01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:0A:0B:0C:0D:0E:0F:10:11:12:13
(R)eject or accept (t)emporarily?
```

I've got no idea where to move from here. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

The certificate is fine when I view the target path in a browser from that machine.

I have managed to interact with that repository path and SSL certificate using TortoiseSVN on my development machine from within a user context. However, the target machine running the automation won't have a user context, so I want to avoid trying to shoehorn TortoiseSVN in if I can possibly avoid it (assuming it would even work, which it may not).

I'm not sure how else I can test the certificate to find out what's wrong with it, if anything.

C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\CHANGES.txt indicates that my current build of Slik SVN is Version 1.8.4